# how toget ordinal number of a day from beginning of year in postgresql?

Tags: postgresql, date

I have a table like

| id | created_at |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 2022-03-01 |
| 2 | 2022-03-23 |

The result should be

| id | days_from_the_beginning_of_year |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 60 |
| 2 | 82 |

I can create a table like

| date | days_from_the_beginning_of_a_leap_year | days_from_the_beginning_of_a_non_leap_year |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2022-01-01 | 1 | 1 |
| 2022-01-02 | 2 | 2 |
| ... | ... | ... |
| 2022-03-01 | 61 | 60 |

But is there a function that does it from the box?

Comment: Welcome to the DBA.SE community. 
Please take a look at [the tour](https://dba.stackexchange.com/tour) and 
how to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://dba.stackexchange.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you are looking for `EXTRACT`:

```
SELECT extract(doy FROM current_date);

 extract 
═════════
      47
(1 row)
```